# String array problem when getfile() returns no matches

Tags: c#, string

I've been tasked to code a little app in c# which searches a directory for a given filetype. I am testing with .txt files, but the app is intended for .epl files for Zebra printers.

I am trying to write it in such a way that:

aO If .epl file is found, send to Printer, delete .epl file then wait a few seconds. 
Search directory again for .epl file, send to printer, delete.

If .epl file is not found, wait a few seconds, repeat until .epl file is found. Repeat a)

The problem arises when Directory.GetFiles(@s1, "*.txt") finds no .txt files at all and tries to run along with the rest of the program.

I get: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

I'm not sure what to do, I believe it's to do with null exceptions? My code is not complete as this problem has me stumped; I'm also a novice and so it's not the cleanest of code.

Code as follows: http://pastebin.com/BHNAtTsk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're indiscriminately using `filePaths[0]` even though the array may be empty. It's not actually to do with null values at all. `GetFiles()` always returns an array, but it will be an empty array if no matching files are found.

I believe you should simply change your condition to:

```
if (filePaths.Length > 0)
```

Comment: Simple solution, worked no problems. Thanks!
I need my morning coffee :p

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@s1, "*.txt");
if ((filePaths[0]).Length > 1)   .....
```

From the documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx

> If there are no files, this method returns an empty array.

So the appropriate check is instead:

```
if (filePaths.Length > 0)
```